# Error in email template for Robot framework when using multiple script blocks in pipeline

Tags: email, templates, robotframework, pipeline

Im using Jenkins in Windows 10 with pipeline script running a robot script and then sending a email with the results.
The template I'm using is [this opne](https://github.com/vladwa/robot-email-template)

I've tried using different setups in the jenkinsfile (including using a scripted version) but basically this works:

```
    pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {              
                script{
                    bat "robot -v store:${storeID} -v testType:${testType} -v site:${pageID} -v productName: previews.robot"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always{
            script{
                    step(
                        [
                            $class              : 'RobotPublisher',
                            outputPath          : '.',
                            outputFileName      : 'output.xml',
                            reportFileName      : 'report.html',
                            logFileName         : 'log.html',
                            disableArchiveOutput: false,
                            passThreshold       : 50,
                            unstableThreshold   : 40,
                            otherFiles          : "*.png",
                        ]
                    )
                    def emailBody = '''${SCRIPT, template="robot.template"}'''
                    emailext body: emailBody,
                    subject: "[JENKINS BUILD]",
                    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
            }
            archiveArtifacts '*.html, *.xml, *.png'
        }   
    }
}
```

But if I add another stage with some scripting, as for example, change the build name, then I will get a template error.
Pipeline that generates error:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Init'){
            steps{
                script{
                    def name = ""
                    switch(testType){
                        case "newProduct":
                            def tmpProduct = pageID.split("/")
                            productName = tmpProduct[tmpProduct.size()-1]
                            name= storeID+": New Product ("+productName+")"
                        break
                        case "newHomepage":
                            name = storeID+": New Homepage"
                        break
                        case "newBlog":
                            name = storeID+": New Blog Post"
                        break
                        case "cosmetics":
                            name = storeID+": UI Changes"
                        break
                        default:
                            name = "Test type empty"
                        break
                    }
                    currentBuild.displayName = name
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script{
                    bat "robot -v store:${storeID} -v testType:${testType} -v site:${pageID} -v productName: previews.robot"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always{
            script{
                    step(
                        [
                            $class              : 'RobotPublisher',
                            outputPath          : '.',
                            outputFileName      : 'output.xml',
                            reportFileName      : 'report.html',
                            logFileName         : 'log.html',
                            disableArchiveOutput: false,
                            passThreshold       : 50,
                            unstableThreshold   : 40,
                            otherFiles          : "*.png",
                        ]
                    )
                    def emailBody = '''${SCRIPT, template="robot.template"}'''
                    emailext body: emailBody,
                    subject: "[JENKINS BUILD]",
                    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
            }
            archiveArtifacts '*.html, *.xml, *.png'
        }   
    }
}
```

The name of the build is changed correctly and the script runs to the end without issues BUT in the email and console output I can see a template error:

```
Exception raised during template rendering: Cannot get property 'simpleName' on null object

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'simpleName' on null object
```

Any Pointers? I would really like to make a pipeline more rich but I will stay with the basic if I can't solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Modify robot.template as below,which solved this problem.

```
if( action && (action.class.simpleName.equals("RobotBuildAction") ) )
```